# Calculation of differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have following problem:

$\dot{x}(t)=r_1(t)x(t)-d(t)-u_2-\alpha u_{2}$

$\dot{y}(t)=r_2(t)y(t)+u_2$

where $ u_2, \alpha$ are constants and initial conditions are: $x(0)=x_0$, $y(0)=y_0$

Can someone help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are the equations supposed to be uncoupled?

Comment: @eyeballfrog yes